# NPM to pull from private GitLab repository

Tags: node.js, git, npm, gitlab

I have a GitLab domain, project and repo. This project is accessible via a group I am apart of.

I would like for this to be downloaded via `npm install` in the following ways:

- Local computer
- GitLab CI job
- Inside of a Docker container

I'm guessing the easiest way of doing this is to just make it public. Is there a way to fix this so it is secure. I can imagine that it must be done with keys.

In my `package.json` under dependencies I currently have this, but it gives a 401 error of course:

```
"my-module": "my-domain.com:my-project/my-repo#my-branch",
```

I do not want hardcoded tokens in the `package.json` file, if it can be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SSH keys to access your repository. Add ssh keys to GitLab server and define url to your repsitory in following form:

`git+ssh://git@git.mydomain.com:Username/Repository#{branch|tag}`

or

`git+ssh://git@git.mydomain.com/Username/Repository#{branch|tag}`

In your `package.json` it will be something like this `"my-module": "git+ssh://git@my-domain.com:my-project/my-repo#my-branch"`

If your ssh key is password protected, then npm will ask for password.

Comment: I tried this from my local computer and it isn't working. NPM will not install it, I get the 401 error. I can git clone the repository though. So don't really know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are your ssh keys on server correct? I just tried the solution with my private repository on `https://gitlab.com` and it worked fine. Can you run `npm i --loglevel verbose` and post the authentication part? Or post logs from GitLab server where is your authentication attempt.

Comment: Well I'm sure they are since I said I can git clone the repo no problem :) (the key I'm talking about is the one in my profile settings).

Comment: Can you post the part from `npm i --loglevel verbose` output where is your private package installed?

Comment: This is not true, you can only target a branch with your synthax.Also, github allow you to get a tag using `#semver:^1.0.0` but that does not apply to gitlab.